# Case of equality in Markov's inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

> Find an example where Markov's inequality is tight in the following sense: For each positive integer $a$, find a non-negative random variable $X$ such that $P(X\ge a)=E(X)/a$.

How to do this problem, I am really confused. Also, what is the definition of Markov's inequality?

Answer (score 8):

Markov inequality is the integrated version of the almost sure inequality $a\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant a}\leqslant X$ hence the equality case happens if and only if $a\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant a}=X$ almost surely, that is, $X\in\{0,a\}$ almost surely.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by "Markov inequality is the integrated version of the almost sure inequality", I know what almost sure inequality is but I don't understand it's relation with Markov's inequality.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable with a finite expectation $E(X)$. Markov's Inequality states that in that case, for any positive real number $a$, we have
$$\Pr(X\ge a)\le \frac{E(X)}{a}.$$

In order to understand what that means, take an exponentially distributed random variable with density function $\frac{1}{10}e^{-x/10}$ for $x\ge 0$, and density $0$ elsewhere. Then the mean of $X$ is $10$.

Take $a=100$. Markov's Inequality says that 
$$\Pr(X\ge 100)\le \frac{E(X)}{100}=\frac{10}{100}.$$

It is straightforward to show that for this exponential, we have $\Pr(X\ge 100)=e^{-100/10}$.  This is a number that is very close to $0$.

Note that the Markov Inequality did not lie. The probability that $X\ge 100$ really is $\le \frac{1}{10}$. But $e^{-10}$ is **very much** less than $\frac{1}{10}$. So in this case the Markov Inequality produced a correct but lousy bound for the "tail probability" of the exponential.

Could we produce a **general** but better bound. Yhe purpose of the exercise is to show that in a sense we cannot.

That is the price we pay for having a theorem that applies to **all** random variables that have a finite expectation. The bound produced by the Markov Inequality is often not at all sharp.

The question asks us, given a positive integer $a$, to produce a random variable $X=X_a$ such that $\Pr(X\ge a)=\frac{E(X)}{a}$.

We can produce a very boring random variable that will do the job. Let $X=a$ with probability $1$. Then $\Pr(X\ge a)=1$. You should show that in this case, $\frac{E(X)}{a}=1$. That will show that it is perfectly possible to have $\Pr(X\ge a)$ exactly equal to $\frac{E(X)}{a}$.

Comment: Very good explanation indeed. I had one question bothering me which is "What if a is smaller than the expected value of X. In this case, we get **Pr(X>=a) <= i**, where i is greater than 1 which is true but I just don't feel okay that the bound here is such loose. Am I missing something here?